# Subtrair dias de um input date com javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, data, input

Preciso pegar um os dados de um campo type number e somar a uma data de um `input` date. Eu já consegui, porém preciso agora pegar o resultado dessa data e subtrair 14 dias, mas não to conseguindo. Sou iniciante e preciso fazer isso, me ajudem por favor. O que eu preciso fazer para subtrair 14 ao resultado do input date `datafin`?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="date" id="ini" />
<input onchange="calculater();" name="dias" type="number" id="dias" min="20" max="40" size="70" />
<input name="datafin" type="date" id="datafin" size="70" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
function calculater() {
    var inicial = document.getElementById("ini").value;
    var dias = parseInt(document.getElementById("dias").value);
    var partes = datainicial.split("-");
    var ano = partes[0];
    var mes = partes[1] - 1;
    var dia = partes[2];

    inicial = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
    final = new Date(inicial);
    final.setDate(final.getDate() + dias);

    var dd = ("0" + final.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var mm = ("0" + (final.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var y = final.getFullYear();

    var dataformatada = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById('datafin').value = dataformatada;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi. Você quer somar pela quantidade do `input` e subtrair 14 dias do resultado?

Comment: Existe o input Number que vai entre 20 e 40, esse input soma com o que o usuário marcar no primeiro input date, se ele marcar dia 01 no date e 20 no number o resultado será marcado com dia 21 no segundo input date, porém preciso pegar o resultado desse segundo input date e subtrair 14 dias.

Comment: O resultado desse segundo `input` já deverá ser o valor - 14 dias ou não?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var data = new Date();

document.write('Hoje é: ' + data.toLocaleString());

data.setDate(data.getDate() - 14);

document.write('<br>14 dias atrás: ' + data.toLocaleString());
```

No seu caso:

```js
function calculater() {
  var inicial = document.getElementById("ini").value;
  var dias = parseInt(document.getElementById("dias").value);
  var partes = inicial.split("-");
  var ano = partes[0];
  var mes = partes[1] - 1;
  var dia = partes[2];

  inicial = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
  final = new Date(inicial);
  final.setDate(final.getDate() + dias);
  final.setDate(final.getDate() - 14); // menos 14 dias do resultado

  var dd = ("0" + final.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var mm = ("0" + (final.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var y = final.getFullYear();

  var dataformatada = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
  document.getElementById('datafin').value = dataformatada;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="ini" />
<input onchange="calculater();" name="dias" type="number" id="dias" min="20" max="40" size="70" />
<input name="datafin" type="date" id="datafin" size="70" />
```

Comment: Lucas, e como seria para passar o valor do input date datafin, pois eu precisava subtrair de acordo com o resultado que aparecesse da soma entre o dia que o usuário marcar, com o input number que ele marcar também. Esse resultdo é apresentado em outro input date, agora preciso pegar o valor desse resultado e subtrair 14.

Comment: esta resposta tem um problema grave, quando o dia final passar o número de dias do mês corrente. Veja a minha resposta para ver como trabalhar com isso.

Comment: [Dessa forma](https://jsfiddle.net/t3kqkr1k/) você diz @jsbueno? Li sua resposta, está boa..se puder simular o problema (talvez no fiddle) por favor.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**:
O mais correto é algo do tipo:

```
inicial = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
milissegundos_por_dia = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
data_final = new Date(inicial.getTime() + dias * milissegundos_por_dia);
```

**explicando**:

O objeto `Date` do Javascript possui alguns métodos convenientes, para acessar cada tipo de valor associado à data que ele contém.

O método `.getDate` em particular recupera o dia do mês, como um número inteiro. O problema ao querer subtrair datas usando o `getDate()` é quando se chega nas "fronteiras" de um mês: tudo bem se for dia 15 e você quer a data de 2 dias atrás - `getDate()` retorna 15, você tira 2, tem 13, faz um `setDate`, e tem a data correta de 2 dias atrás.

O problema é se você está no dia 7 e quer a data de 15 dias atrás. Ou simplesmente quer a data de 30 dias atrás. Usando o getDate, você teria que fazer uma estrutura de `if` e `else` para quando o dia do mês desejado fosse negativo, subtrair um do mês, e aí ajustar o dia apropriadamente. E mais um `if` para o caso do mês que voltou ser de Janeiro pra Dezembro, e nesse caso, subtrair o ano. 
Isso para não mencionar os inúmeros corner-cases, como os bissextos, início e fim de horário de verão, etc... pode parecer trivial a principio, mas sempre é legal ter em mente que a própria Microsoft, nas primeiras versões do Excel errou o cálculo de datas para o ano de 1900 (tratando-o como bissexto, sendo que não era - e até hoje o formato de datas codificado em arquivos .XLS sofre por conta desse erro).

Felizmente, o objeto `Date` também tem os métodos `getTime` e `setTime`, que  em vez de dizer uma data como mês, dia, ano, horas, minutos e segundos em campos separados, devolve (e aceita) um único número inteiro: O número de milissegundos passados desde a meia noite de 1/1/1970.

Essa representação deriva do chamado "unixtime", usado em servidores e programas no mundo inteiro - que representa o número de segundos passado desde a mesma data. (veja que em Javascript, temos os milissegundos, não os segundos).

Então, dada uma data, tudo o que precisamos fazer para calcular a subtração (ou adição) de um certo número de dias é usar o `.getTime`, manipular esse número, e usar o `.setTime` ou criar um novo objeto `Date` para ter como obter os valores "utilizáveis por humanos", de mês, dia e ano, da data desejada.

Ou seja:

```
...
ano = ...;
mes = ...;
dia = ...;
...
dias = ...; 
...
inicial = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
milissegundos_por_dia = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
data_final = new Date(inicial.getTime() + dias * milissegundos_por_dia);
```

E pronto - você tem a data final sem nenhum problema de cálculo de mês, virada do ano, leap second - você reusa todas as milhares de linhas de código que estão no navegador e no sistema operacional para calcular a data, sem precisar reinventar a roda.