# Funcao adicionar Anos ao campo date Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso de um código em Javascript que adicione anos a data selecionada

```js
function calculaData() {
var datainicial = document.getElementById("dataselecionada").value;
var partes = datainicial.split("-");
var ano = partes[0];
var mes = partes[1]-1;
var dia = partes[2];

datainicial = new Date(ano,mes,dia);
datafinal = new Date(datainicial);

//quantidade de dias
datafinal.setDate(datafinal.getDate() + 1);

var dd = ("0" + datafinal.getDate()).slice(-2);
var mm = ("0" + (datafinal.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
var y = datafinal.getFullYear();

//var dataformatada = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
var dataformatada = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.getElementById('dataAtualizada').value = dataformatada;

}
```

```html
<label>Data</label>
<input type="date" id="dataselecionada" value="2018-03-10">
<br>
<p>Após adicionar um ano aparce o resultado abaixo no campo date</p>
<label>Data atualizada</label>
<input type="date" id="dataAtualizada">
<p>Exemplo 10/03/2019</p>

<input type="button" onclick="calculaData()" value="Calcular">
```

resumo: pegar data devolver no campo date Data atualizada com a soma de um ano. Eu consegui com dias mas não consigo adicionar ano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça como abaixo:

```js
function addZeroAesqueda(texto, tamanhoMaximo){
  texto = texto.toString();
  while (texto.length < tamanhoMaximo){
     texto = "0"+texto;
  }
 return texto;
}

document.getElementById('dataselecionada').onchange =function(e){
  let dataDigitada = e.target.value;
  let dataDigitadaSplit = dataDigitada.split("/");
  console.log('dataDigitada',dataDigitada)
  
  let dia = dataDigitadaSplit[0]; 
  let mes = dataDigitadaSplit[1];
  let ano = dataDigitadaSplit[2];
  
  
  if(ano.length <4 && parseInt(ano) < 50){
    ano = "20"+ano;
  }else if(ano.length <4 && parseInt(ano) >= 50){
    ano = "19"+ano;
  }
  ano = parseInt(ano);
  mes = mes -1;
  
  let data = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
  data.setFullYear(data.getFullYear()+1)
  
  ano= addZeroAesqueda(data.getFullYear(), 4);
  mes= addZeroAesqueda(data.getMonth()+1, 2);
  dia= addZeroAesqueda(data.getDate(), 2);
  
       
  document.getElementById('dataAtualizada').value = ano+'-'+mes+'-'+dia ;
};
```

```html
<label>Data</label>
<input type="text" id="dataselecionada" value="10/03/18">
<br>
<p>Após adicionar um ano aparce o resultado abaixo no campo date</p>
<label>Data atualizada</label>
<input type="date" id="dataAtualizada">
<p>Exemplo 10/03/2019</p>
```

Comment: Se a data digitada for "29/02/16", o resultado será "2017-02-29", mas 2017 não é ano bissexto, então 29/02 é uma data inválida neste ano. Talvez seja melhor adaptar as respostas [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176793/112052), ou usar uma lib como o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add), que já faz as contas se preocupando com esses detalhes todos. Cálculos com datas é mais complicado do que parece, e abordagens mais "simples" (e eu diria até "ingênuas") podem até "funcionar" para muitos casos, mas há muitas exceções e casos especiais para se atentar.